# Show top commenters without using a plugin

Tags: functions, comments

I'm trying to create a small list of top commenters in my sidebar.
I don't want to use a plugin, so I was googling for codes.
All I could find was the following:

```
function top_comment_authors($amount = 5){

    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results('
        SELECT
            COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
        FROM
            '.$wpdb->comments.'
        WHERE
            comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1
        GROUP BY
            comment_author_email
        ORDER BY
            comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
        LIMIT '.$amount

    );

    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach($results as $result){
        $output .= "<li>".$result->comment_author."</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";

    echo $output;

}
```

I already modified it because I also want the post count and author url to show up. I also want to add a gravatar later on.
However, it just displays everything next to each other:

[image]

```
$output .= "<li>".$result->comment_author. $result->comments_count. $result->comment_author_url."</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";

    echo $output;

}
```

Whenever I try to add something, I end up getting an error message. I'm pretty sure I need to modify the little code above if I want to change the way it's displayed, but HOW?! :/

This is how I call the function, so no room for customization other than in the function.php, right?:

```
<?php top_comment_authors(); ?>
```

I'm not really good with PHP, so I wonder how I'd do something like this:

[gravatar] "commenters-name-as-url-if-available" (comment-count)
e.g. "japanworm (45)"

If anybody could help me a little, that would be great.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output .= "<li>".(($result->comment_author_url) ? "<a href='".$result->comment_author_url."'>" : "").$result->comment_author.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "</a>" : "")." (".$result->comments_count.")</li>";
```

edit:
to show the avatar before the name:

```
$output .= "<li>".get_avatar($result->comment_author_email, 45).' '.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "<a href='".$result->comment_author_url."'>" : "").$result->comment_author.(($result->comment_author_url) ? "</a>" : "")." (".$result->comments_count.")</li>";
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much. This works well! However, I also want a gravatar to be shown. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work: `<ul> <li> <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?> <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, '45' ); ?> <?php } ?> <?php top_comment_authors(); ?></li> </ul>`

Comment: I have expanded my answer with a possible code to show the avatar before the name.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!! Works perfectly fine! :)